# Call Meteor helper function when adding elements to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I want to call a `UI.registerHelper('getTitle', function (type){});` function when adding an element with jQuery's `.append($('<h3/>', {'class': 'panel', html: "{{getTitle 'game'}}"})`.
The output is: `{{getTitle 'game'}}`, so it's not interpreted.
How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't proceed this way, because {{getTitle "game"}} is not HTML, it's actually Spacebars syntax and it cannot be dynamically interpreted like this.

What you could do is declare the getTitle as a separate function :

```
function getTitle(type){
  //
}
Template.registerHelper("getTitle",getTitle);
```

And use it in your DOM insertion code :

```
var html=getTitle("game");
// ... proceed with insertion via jQuery
```

Most important, adding HTML via jQuery doesn't sound very meteorish so I advise you to reconsider your design and switch to a template based approach :

```
<template name="whatever">
  {{#id conditionMet}}
    <h3>{{getTitle "game"}}</h3>
  {{/if}}
</template>

Template.whatever.helpers({
  conditionMet:function(){
    // return some value based on a reactive data source
  }
});
```